# How to automatically save ontology's changes from Protege to github

Tags: protege

I am very new on Protege, what I am trying to accomplish now, is any changes I make to an Ontology that I have constructed in Protege, to be automatically (without the use of any local repository) changed and stored in a github repository or a public link (website e.t.c.). Do this kind of tools exist? Can you provide me an idea? I searched over the google without any success...

Comment: I see only limited solution.
Intellij Idea has great support github/git, and there are several plugins that support RDF/SPARQL/endpoints. But no OWL with axioms, etc.

Comment: If  I don't use github. but a custom repository/webpage, can it work as I described before? Thanks...

Comment: Ok, I think I  have found something... Any idea what these commands are?? https://github.com/perma-id/w3id.org/blob/master/games/spec/.htaccess

Answer (score -1):

Basically what do these lines mean?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} !application/rdf\+xml.*(text/html|application/xhtml\+xml|text/\*|\*/\*)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/html [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/xhtml\+xml [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/\* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} \*/\* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/.*
...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} ^.*application/rdf\+xml.* 
...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} ^.*text/turtle.*
```

I am also trying to figure out with apache tutorials..! Thanks!